Problemas con la renderización en react
Estoy empezando un nuevo proyecto con la finalidad de aprender mejor la renderización de componentes en react. Pero tengo un problema con este código y, con sinceridad, no sé por qué:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ComponentB from "./componentB";

export default function A() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
           .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) setData(response.json());
            })
           .catch(error => setError(error))
           .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
    }, [])

    return (
        <main>
            {isLoading && 
                <p>Cargando ...</p>
            }
            {!isLoading && error && 
                <h4>Componente A: Ha ocurrido un error</h4>
            }
            {!isLoading && !error && data && 
                <ComponentB></ComponentB>
            }
            {!isLoading && !error && !data && 
                <h4>Component A: No se ha obtenido data</h4>
            }
        </main>
    )
}

La idea es sencilla (al menos la explicación lo es), simplemente tengo un componente A que pide una petición HTTP GET a una API. Mientras que no obtenga los datos, el componente A mostrará unos mensajes dependiendo de varias situaciones (si está cargando o si hay error en la respuesta de la petición), pero si llega a obtener los datos, mostrará los mensajes que tiene el component B.
El problema surge en que al parecer lo estoy haciendo mal, ya que mi página solamente muestra el mensaje de "Cargando ...".
Intenté agregar un console.log(response)al fetch a ver si se obtenía los datos:
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
           .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.ok) setData(response.json());
            })
           .catch(error => setError(error))
           .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));

Pero en la consola no apareció nada. Entonces, decidí agregar un mensaje al iniciar el useEffect:
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect en progreso ...");
    // el resto de la función
}, []);

Pero ese mensaje jamás se imprime. Es que como si nunca entrara en el useEffect.
Quisiera que me ayudaran a poder entender qué es lo que está sucediendo.

Encontré la respuesta, no se trataba de un error de código por parte del componente, sino de quién llamaba al componente A.
Yo estoy usando Astro para este proyecto, y mi page era la siguiente:
---
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.astro';
import ComponentA from '../components/componentA';
---

<Layout title="Pruebas">
    <h3>Componentes con React</h3>
    <ComponentA></ComponentA>
</Layout>

<style>
</style>

Agregando el client:load al componente A, sí funciona el useEffect.
---
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.astro';
import ComponentA from '../components/componentA';
---

<Layout title="Pruebas">
    <h3>Componentes con React</h3>
    <ComponentA client:load></ComponentA>
</Layout>

<style>
</style>


A pesar de que hayas arreglado el problema, tenés un error a la hora de obtener los datos, esto no va a setear los datos correctamente:
if (response.ok) setData(response.json());

response.json devuelve una Promesa, primero debes resolverla antes de pasar los datos al estado, lo podes solucionar devolviendo la promesa para encadenar otro then que ahora si tendrá los datos que podrás setear en el estado del componente.
Otro pequeño error es que response.ok no lanza un error, solo indica mediante un boolean si el código de estado de la solicitud corresponde a una solicitud exitosa (códigos 200-299). Para arreglarlo, puedes lanzar un error explícitamente con la palabra clave throw en caso de que response.ok sea false.
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) return response.json(); // paso la promesa al siguiente then
        else throw new Error(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText) // o lanzo un error que sera capturado en el catch
      })
      .then(data => setData(data))
      .catch(error => setError(error))
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, [])


el primer error que comentas me di cuenta después, es bueno saberlo que se resolvía con otro then, yo opté por volverlo una función asíncrona, y utilizar un await. El segundo error que me dices, sí estaba pensando obtenerlo más adelante, lo que pasa es que cuando me di cuenta que no funcionaba el useEffect, en ese momento no importaba lo demás  de igual forma, muchas gracias por tus consejos
